# SqlEntityConnection configured with a local schema file

Tags: f#, type-providers, entityconnection

I want to use the SqlEntityConnection type provider in f# to query and update a db.
It works well when I use it with the connection string pointing to a live SQL Server DataBase.

```
type EntityConnection = SqlEntityConnection<"Data Source=myServer;Initial Catalog=myDb;...", Pluralize=true>
```

Now I want to get rid of the dependency with the live DB and, instead, use a local schema file. Given what I read on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh362322.aspx), I gave a try to the following line:

```
type private EntityConnection = SqlEntityConnection<LocalSchemaFile="mySchemaFile.ssdl", Pluralize=true>
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't compile and the compiler's message is:

> Error 46  The type provider 'Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.DesignTime.DataProviders' reported an error: When using this provider you must specify either a connection string or a connection string name. To specify a connection string, use SqlEntityConnection<"...connection string...">.

So what should I do? If I leave the connection string, I have the feeling that I don't really turn off the dependency to the DB. For instance, if I try to switch the Data Source with a non-existing server, it doesn't compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide a connection string name, along with a connection string in the configuration file.
You can still provide a localschemafile that will be used to cache locally the schema.

If you put the schema file under source control, the connection string will only be used as a default when calling `GetDataContext()` without parameter, but not when building or editing code.

You also need to set the parameter ForceUpdate to False.